# angularjs directive works on jsfiddle, but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to create  tags to use YT videos on my website. Everything works on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kertp/7GPBZ/8/), but using the same code on my server doesn't work. The query made is to localhost:5000/{{url}} and obviously it fails. Where can I find the problem?

```
'use strict';

var module = angular.module('App')
  .controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope) {
})
.directive('youtube', function ($sce) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
          video: '@video'
      },
      link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('video', function (video_id) {
           scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id);
        });
      },
      template: "<iframe width='560' height='315' src={{url}} frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>",
    };
});
```

I use ui-view class in index.html and use the tag in profile.html

```
<youtube video="aOD43neIwO4"></youtube>
```

I'm using angularjs version 1.2.11

Comment: Can you share the relevant markup from index.html and profile.html?

Comment: I notice a difference between your fiddler code and what you have posted here is missing quotes around the src attribute. May I also suggest using ng-source and escaping double quotes in your template string. `"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" ng-src=\"{{url}}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"`

Comment: Thank you! ng-src did work. I'm quite new to Angular and forgot the fact.